# Stop RStudio creating two files on start up

Tags: r, rstudio

It appears that every time RStudio starts up it creates two blank source files called 'Untitled1' and 'Untitled2'. Is there a way to prevent these files from being created?

Comment: Just to be sure: it's actually *creating* the files each time? Or is it possible that those two files got created somewhere along the way, and then were never closed or deleted, and are just being reopened RStudio reloading the workspace each time it starts?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and then on again? Jokes aside, I haven't heard of anything like that happening, but reinstalling RStudio might clear it up.

Comment: Have you looked at your r.profile file? ```usethis::edit_r_profile()``` if something is happening in there.